# Selecting columns in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Just curious, and quite new to Panda in Python,

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Is there an effective way to select column `a`, `b`, then from `j` to `t` only, resulting in the output to be like this,

```
   a  b  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

I can try,

```
original_column = original_dataframe[['a', 'b'...]]
```

But that will be too much of a hassle I rather use indexes but don't know how

Comment: `.loc` in pandas support slice object  like `j:t`

Comment: .. warning:: Note that contrary to usual python slices, **both** the
      start and the stop are included

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = df[['a','b'] + df.loc[:, 'j':'t'].columns.tolist()]
print (df)
   a  b  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df[['a','b']], df.loc[:, 'j':'t']], axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Comment: mighty thanks, now I can effectively select multiple columns in different positions and ranges

Answer (score 1):

try to drop the columns

```
 df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
```

You will get the df just with the columns are remaining.

Comment: I am not a troll. You can drop the columns.